# CSS/HTML: Remove image filter on click

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover

I use some images as links on my site. When I hover the mouse over one of the images, they go from gray to color - and they go back to gray when the mouse is no longer hovering.

I want the image to stay colorized when activated. Say I click the image, it should stay colorized until another link is clicked/activated.

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<p><a href="privileged.php" target="testframe">
<img class="grayscale" height="67" src="powerlogo.png" width="303">
</a></p>
<iframe name="testframe"></iframe>
```

CSS:

```
img.grayscale {
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
  filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
}

a:hover img, a:focus img {
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

The above works as intended in Firefox, but not in Chrome and IE.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It can not be done using css, i think.

Comment: As long as the user clicks nowhere else, the link should be in its `:active` state, so try formatting the image inside that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add/toggle a class with javascript to your element and style this with css:

```
$("a").click(function(){
  $("a").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});

a:hover img,
a:focus img,
a.active img {
  filter: none;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/3uYDc/

Comment: Thanks alot, this worked perfectly. But please take it easy, I was at work so I haven't been able to answer before now.